# How to provide data to a minion from an orchestration?

Tags: salt-stack

I have an orchestration file that calls a series of custom salt-runner modules. One of the modules creates a piece of data that the targeted minion needs.

What's the preferred way of providing this to a minion? I am assuming that I should add this to pillar but do not know how to do this from a salt-module

Comment: Is the data secret at all? Does it matter if the minion can change it? How will the minion be using it? When does the minion need it - when this orch applies a state to it, or always in future?

Comment: The data is secret. The minion cannot change it. The data should be applied during orchestration.

Answer (score 1):

Orchestration can pass additional pillar data to minions via [`salt.state`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.saltmod.html#salt.states.saltmod.state):

```yaml
apply state:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: my-minion
    - highstate: true
    - pillar:
        foo: {{ bar }}
```